# MediaPipe - Which Image Segmentation Model For Portrait Aspect Ratios

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, mediapipe, semantic-segmentation, tflite

Using MediaPipe Image Segmentation we have two different model options (offered by Google) for aspect ratios of the input, square and landscape as documented here: https://developers.google.com/mediapipe/solutions/vision/image_segmenter/index#models

However, the documentation does not make mention of "portrait" aspect ratios. While it's technically a flipped "landscape" ratio, I'm unsure if it would be best to use "landscape" or "square" for "portrait" dimensions.

Landscape is defined as 144 x 256. Square is defined as 256 x 256.

Does anyone know if I should be using "Landscape" or "Square" for 256 X 144? Or if there is a better model to use for this scenario?

Edit: I see some people are voting to "Close" this but Google's Github account said come ask it here.